# Finding best variable to replace NAs with order of preferred variables

Tags: r, missing-data

I have a data set with many `NAs`.  I want to create a new variable with the value in `variable1`. If `variable1` is NA, then use `variable2` instead. If `variable2` is `NA` too, use `variable3`,etc. I have created a function to do that but it doesn’t work as intended.

```
best_variable <- function(var_best1,var_best2,var_best3){

  if(!is.na(var_best1)) {return(var_best1)}  

  if(is.na(var_best1) & !is.na(var_best2)) {return(var_best2)}

  if(is.na(var_best1) & is.na(var_best2) & !is.na(var_best3)) {return(var_best3)}

  if(is.na(var_best1) & is.na(var_best2) & is.na(var_best3)) {return(NA)}
}
```

See example with mtcars dataset.

```
test <- head(mtcars)

test$vs[3:5] <- NA; test$am[test$am == 1] <- NA

test$new_var <- best_variable(test$vs,
                              test$am,
                              test$gear) 
Not the expected result as new_var[3] should be 4, as test$gear[3] is 4. 

test$new_var <- lapply(mtcars[,.(vs,am,gear)], best_variable) # error

best_variable(test$vs[3],
              test$am[3],
              test$gear[3]) # Gets the right result
```

What am I missing here? Why my function doesn’t work when applied to the whole data set?

Comment: Oddly, you do not mention the warning that you get with `test$new_var <- best_variable(test$vs, test$am,test$gear)`. If you search for this warning on SO or elsewhere, you will quickly figure out that your function is not vectorized.

Comment: `Vectorize(best_variable)(test$vs, test$am, test$gear)` also you can clean up those if statements. for example, you don't need to keep checking for `is.na(var_best1)` after you first checked for `!is.na(var_best1)`

Comment: You also can use `apply` to use the function on each row of your dataframe like this. `apply(test, 1, function(x) best_variable(x["vs"], x["am"], x["gear"]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
best_variable <- function (...) {
  apply(rbind(...), 2, function (a) {na.omit(a)[1]})
}

best_variable (test$vs, test$am, test$gear)

# [1] 0 0 4 0 0 1
```